# Gam is R returning either "degrees of freedom" or "subscript out of bounds" error

Tags: r, gam

I am trying to run a gam model on a small data set

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)

test <- structure(list(x = c(69, 365, 452, 100, 120, 120, 150, 159, 180
), y = c(17.91, 2.58, 4.82, 10.09, 6.24, 10.33, 2.35, 1.94, 3.91
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

This data looks like this

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I'd like to try fitting this data with a spline with gam. I tried the following, which returns an error

```
mod <- gam(test$y ~ s(test$x))
```

> ```
>  Error in smooth.construct.tp.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots) :
>  A term has fewer unique covariate combinations than specified maximum
>  degrees of freedom
> ```

Based on this post http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Help-with-GAM-mgcv-td3074165.html it seems like maybe I need to mandate fewer knots.

I tried telling the model to only use two knots as follows (figuring I'd figure out the optimum number somehow later):

```
mod <- gam(test$y ~ s(test$x), k = 2)
```

> ```
>  Error in data[[txt]] : subscript out of bounds
> ```

I'm not sure what this later error means, or why I am getting it.

Just in case it is of any use, here is the traceback for that error

```
 traceback()
```

> ```
> 7: get.var(object$term[i], knots)
> 6: ExtractData(object, data, knots)
> 5: smooth.construct3(object, data, knots)
> 4: smoothCon(split$smooth.spec[[i]], data, knots, absorb.cons, scale.penalty = scale.penalty, 
>        null.space.penalty = select, sparse.cons = sparse.cons, diagonal.penalty = diagonal.penalty, 
>        apply.by = apply.by, modCon = modCon)
> 3: gam.setup(formula = list(pf = test$y ~ 1, pfok = 1, smooth.spec = list(
>        list(term = "test$x", bs.dim = -1, fixed = FALSE, dim = 1L, 
>            p.order = NA, by = "NA", label = "s(test$x)", xt = NULL, 
>            id = NULL, sp = NULL)), fake.formula = test$y ~ 1 + test$x, 
>        response = "test$y", fake.names = "test$x", pred.names = c("test", 
>        "x"), pred.formula = ~test + x), pterms = test$y ~ 1, data = list(
>        `test$y` = c(17.91, 2.58, 4.82, 10.09, 6.24, 10.33, 2.35, 
>        1.94, 3.91), `test$x` = c(69, 365, 452, 100, 120, 120, 150, 
>        159, 180)), knots = 2, sp = NULL, min.sp = NULL, H = NULL, 
>        absorb.cons = TRUE, sparse.cons = 0, select = FALSE, idLinksBases = TRUE, 
>        scale.penalty = TRUE, paraPen = NULL, drop.intercept = FALSE)
> 2: do.call(gsname, list(formula = gp, pterms = pterms, data = mf, 
>        knots = knots, sp = sp, min.sp = min.sp, H = H, absorb.cons = TRUE, 
>        sparse.cons = 0, select = select, idLinksBases = control$idLinksBases, 
>        scale.penalty = control$scalePenalty, paraPen = paraPen, 
>        drop.intercept = drop.intercept))
> 1: gam(test$y ~ s(test$x), k = 2)
> ```

And session info

```
 sessionInfo()
```

> ```
> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
> Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default
> BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1
>
> locale:
>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
> other attached packages:
> [1] mgcv_1.8-25   nlme_3.1-137  ggplot2_3.1.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>  [1] Rcpp_0.12.19     rstudioapi_0.8   bindr_0.1.1      knitr_1.20       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0   
>  [8] lattice_0.20-38  colorspace_1.3-2 R6_2.3.0         rlang_0.3.0.1    plyr_1.8.4       dplyr_0.7.7      tools_3.5.1     
> [15] grid_3.5.1       packrat_0.4.9-3  gtable_0.2.0     withr_2.1.2      yaml_2.2.0       lazyeval_0.2.1   assertthat_0.2.0
> [22] tibble_1.4.2     crayon_1.3.4     Matrix_1.2-15    bindrcpp_0.2.2   purrr_0.2.5      glue_1.3.0       labeling_0.3    
> [29] compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.3.0     scales_1.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.2
> ```

I am wondering if anyone has suggestions about how I might best deal with this error or otherwise get a working gam with this data. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use k=3 there's no problem (at least with the method I used which passes the dataframe to the `data` argument>

```
> mod <- gam(y ~ s(x, k=3), data=test)
> mod

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, k = 3)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1.95  total = 2.95 

GCV score: 9.922357     
> mod <- gam(y ~ s(x, k=4), data=test)
> 
> mod

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, k = 4)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
2.67  total = 3.67 

GCV score: 7.77551     
> mod <- gam(y ~ s(x, k=5), data=test)
> mod

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, k = 5)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
2.94  total = 3.94 

GCV score: 7.758121
```

Since the GCV score doesn't increase when increasing from 4 to 5 I'm showing what you get with k=4:

```
 > mod <- gam(y ~ s(x, k=4), data=test)
> png()
> plot(mod)
> points(y~x, data=test)
> dev.off()
RStudioGD 
        2
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure that the reason for the offset of `s(x,2.67)` from the points is failure to include the intercept term, which would be another (unplotted) "degree of freedom". If you want the predictions of the full model (which will go through the data points, rather than just the contribution from the smoothing term, then plot `predict(mod, newdata=list( x= seq(min(x),max(x), length=100)))` against that same sequence.

Comment: One thing about your solution that took me a little while to notice, is that the `k = 3` term goes inside of the `s()` function, rather than the `gam` function. So its `gam(y ~ s(x, k=3), data=test)` as you correctly wrote, and not `gam(y ~ s(x), k = 3, data=test)` which is what would happen if one just replaced the 2 with 3 in my version.

Comment: Ah. Good that you poinmted that out for the next viewer. I missed that. Sorry I wasn't able to explain why the "naked" `s(x)` didn't work, but I just don't know enough gam-magic.